# Ckeditor4-react and upload video feature

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, ckeditor4-react

I've used `ckeditor4-react` on my React.js app and I want to add an upload video feature to it, but I don't have any idea.
This is the Ckeditor config object:

```
export const ckeditorConfig =  {
    toolbar: [
        { name: 'document', items: [ 'Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard', items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
        { name: 'editing', items: [ 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt' ] },
        { name: 'forms', items: [ 'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 'HiddenField' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'CopyFormatting', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl', 'Language' ] },
        { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },
        { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
        { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
        { name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks' ] },
        { name: 'about', items: [ 'About' ] }
    ],
    toolbarGroups: [
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'forms' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'document',       groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'others' },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
        { name: 'about' }
    ],
    extraPlugins: 'justify, colorbutton, font'
};
```

Comment: I guess this page is your best bet. https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_file_browser_api.html

Comment: On another note, you might wanna take a look at CKEditor 5